# Finding the counter-clockwise direction of points in 3d

Tags: geometry, 3d, polygons

I have a set of 5 points of a polygon in 3d. I want to order these points in a counter-clockwise direction.  How do I do this?

In 2d, to check if two points are ordered counter-clockwise or clockwise, you compute the area (with the origin as (0,0)) $\frac{1}{2}ab$, and if the sign is +ve then the two points are ordered counter-clockwise, and vice-versa.

In 3d, you can compute $\frac{1}{2}|a \times b|$, where $\times$ is the cross product, and $|$ is the magnitude, and therefore this will always return a positive number.

Ultimately, I want to compute the normal of a polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 3 points $A, B, C$. Take the cross product $AB \times AC$. This gives you the normal vector to the plane. If this normal vector points to you, then $A, B, C$ is in a counter clockwise position. You can check if this vector is pointing away from or towards you by taking the dot product of that vector and the vector in the direction you are viewing.

Comment: Ah yes I did read that if the dot product between two points is between 0 and 90°, dot product is positive, and greater than 90° and less than 180°, dot product is negative. Thank you.